# How to Parse a JsonSluper object?

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have the following `JsonSluper` object :

```
[ [id:5017,feature:age,value:20],
  [id:2017,feature:city,value:paris],
  [id:3017,feature:country,value:france] ]
```

and I want to get the following `JsonObject`:

```
"person":{
    "age":20,
    "city":paris,
    "country":france
}
```

I want to transform the `feature` value of the `JsonSluper` to a field of the `JsonObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THat's a Map, not a *"JsonSlurper object"*

Assuming you have something like:

```
def object = [[id:5017,feature:'age',value:20],[id:2017,feature:'city',value:'paris'],[id:3017,feature:'country',value:'france']]
```

Then just do:

```
def json = new JsonBuilder(object).toPrettyString()
```

Then `json` will be a pretty json representation like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5017,
        "feature": "age",
        "value": 20
    },
    {
        "id": 2017,
        "feature": "city",
        "value": "paris"
    },
    {
        "id": 3017,
        "feature": "country",
        "value": "france"
    }
]
```

To do the transformation, just do:

```
def transformed = object.collectEntries { [it.feature, it.value] }
def json = new JsonBuilder(transformed).toPrettyString()
```